# Summing values from user input while looping (C++)

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program in which a user will be prompted to enter an integer 3 times. After each integer, a sum will be displayed after the input. Then, with the second and third integers, the numbers should be added onto the initial sum within a loop. Here is what I have done:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {

double number=0, total=0;


    for (double n=0; n<3; n++){
   cout << "Enter an integer: ";
   cin >> number;

   cout << "Sum is: " << number <<endl;
   total+=number; }

}
```

This is the output so far:

```
Enter an integer: 2                                                                                 
Sum is: 2                                                                                           
Enter an integer: 3                                                                                 
Sum is: 3                                                                                           
Enter an integer: 4                                                                                 
Sum is: 4
```

The goal is for the integers to continue to add to the sum until the loop is done. This is the output that I am trying to achieve:

```
Enter an integer: 2                                                                                 
Sum is: 2                                                                                           
Enter an integer: 3                                                                                 
Sum is: 5                                                                                           
Enter an integer: 4                                                                                 
Sum is: 9
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I am confused on how to solve this part, and it is the only part I need to figure out in order to complete it. Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: You should probably output `total`, not `number`.

Comment: @tkausl You are right on one step, thank you. Rietty solved my problem and now it functions as expected! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << "Sum is: " << number << endl;
```

In this line you are printing the current number, not the total. You need to use `total` instead.

Also move `total += number;` before the previous line. Else you will be one step behind when displaying.

Thus your code should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  double number=0, total=0;
  for (double n=0; n<3; n++){
    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin >> number;
    total+=number; 
    cout << "Sum is: " << total << endl;
  }
}
```